# How BLL and DAL should communicate, all ways lead to trouble

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, n-tier-architecture

You have to use one of two ways to transfer data between BLL <-> DAL

1- Either put the data in Entity.dll, where DAL and BLL and UI can use Entity.Student which only include student information without any logic.

Increase of coupling:-
This can lead to trouble, for example, if Student was having a ClassID where every student is having only one class to attend.  then the business changed so that Student is having a List.  In that case probably you will re-write a lot of code in all layers (UI, BLL, DAL).

2- DAL is having its own Student, and BLL is having its own Student, then when you pass an object from DAL to BLL, you will need to convert every DALStudent to BLLStudent.

A lot of code:
I even don't like the idea of Translator.dll, still a lot of code, and a little bit wasting of processor cycles.

Is there a way out, what is your opinion\way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use exactly same code for different requirements - you have to deal with it. Although, it is a best practice to use different adapted classes for your UI layer (viewmodels). And you don't need BLL layer at all (well, you need, but only for cross-cutting concerns) - take a look at [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215). And then in case of requirements changing you would need to change only domain object and its mapping to view model  (which could be easily done using tools like [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/))